# How can Appearance be raised via in-game actions?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, social-stats

In my Vampire: the Masquerade game all stat increasing are necessitated by in-game actions to improve the related stat. Other than Vicissitude, what in-game actions would be appropriate to facilitate the permanent increase of the Appearance attribute?

Comment: Just an FYI, you may not get an answer to this - you have eliminated one of the only things I can think of that actually works on Kindred.  It is an otherwise good question.

Comment: Is this a house rule, recommended by the game, or both? Also, can you describe what kind of in-game actions a character must undertake to increase a few of the abilities other than Appearance? Must increases have a magical origin?

Comment: In-game actions for stat increases are rarely magical in nature. Abilities are usually increased by practicing, Willpower and Virtues are usually increased by facing harrowing situations, and Attributes are usually increased by having high Abilities which would impart some benefit to the Attributes; unfortunately Appearance has very little which uses it.

Answer (score 10):

Appearance isn't just the raw materials that come from one's looks; it's also the way one uses first impressions and style to their best effect. Some potential in-game acts that might suggest a rise in Appearance: learning to use makeup to better flatter oneself; buying a new wardrobe (or manipulating fashion trends to make the style you already favor become the in, hot thing.); assuming postures and behaviors that show off your best attributes. These might also facilitate buying other Abilities and Attributes to complement them, just as an increase in Athletics might accompany raising Strength or Dexterity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102600/discussion-on-answer-by-jadasc-how-can-appearance-be-raised-via-in-game-actions).