# Can kindred dye their hair?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I know that kindred can't change their hair's length without ritual, as well as how even some cosmetic surface things like tattoos requite rituals to remain permanent as well, but is there anything on if there's any restrictions on a kindred wishing to *dye* their hair? Just a from a bottle sort of thing?

Or does that work just fine?

It seems like it *should* be fine, but not having found anything official on it myself, I wanted to ask.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? It does address some similar ground. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48550/does-the-appearance-of-a-vampire-remain-the-same-forever/48552#48552

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### They can…it just reverts the next night.

Quoting from page 16 of the 20th Anniversary rules:

> Once a vampire is Embraced, her looks are frozen in time. Her skin will be unnaturally cold to the touch and become paler as she ages, but she will look the same in a thousand years as she does on the night of her Embrace.

Now, if you're talking something like hair chalk or wax, that works fine; it stays in until you wash it out, like any other makeup. But if it involves actually penetrating the keratin of the follicles, that's treated as a change or damage, and resets during the sleep of day.

Comment: if it have bein done by vicissitude, it won't revert until the vampire use 5 blood point to revert it (or if it is a Nosferatu and it may make it prettier).

Comment: @Rorp The OP specified mundane forms of dye, so I limited my answer to that scope.

Comment: I've saw this after send my comment. My bad.